# Espejo Mysql BD

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Quisiera saber si es posible crear un espejo de una base de datos local.
Es decir que la base de datos maestra se encuentre en un servidor a nivel intranet y el esclavo este en un web hosting.

Saludos!!!

Comment: Es posible y no es muy complicado ponerlo en marcha. Dos preguntas: ¿necesitas hacerlo a nivel de todas las bases de datos del servidor o sólo algunas? ¿Necesitas espejo bidireccional o de un solo sentido? Es decir, ¿necesitas que los cambios en el servidor externo de cambien también en el de intranet?

Comment: lograstes hacerlo?

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacerlo asi:
**database primary**

```
mysql>  CREATE USER ' repuser' @' localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY ' 123'  
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.45 sec)

mysql>  GRANT ALL ON rep.* TO ' repuser' @' localhost'  
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql>  flush privileges 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>  exit
```

buscamos el archivo de configuracion mysql
`vim /etc/my.cnf` o en `my.ini` y agregamos estas lineas

```
server-id=1
binlog-do-db=dbtest #cambiamos dbtest por el nombre de tu base de datos
log-bin=mysql-bin
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

`reiniciamos el servico de mysql`
volvemos a conectarnos a la `primary database`:

```
mysql>  GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO ' repuser' @' %'  IDENTIFIED BY ' 123'  
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>  FLUSH PRIVILEGES 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>  use rep 
Database changed
mysql>  FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>  SHOW MASTER STATUS 
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |      323 | dbtest       |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>  exit
Bye
```

guardamos los parametros `Position` y `File` que seran usados mas adelate
ahora hacemos un backup de la base de datos:

```
mysqldump -u root -p dbtest >  dbtest.sql
```

volvemos a conectarnos a la `primary database`

```
mysql>  UNLOCK TABLES
```

**standby server**
ahora vamos al server 2 o en este caso nuestro servidor de respaldo a cual llamaremos `standby database` y editamos el archivo `vim /etc/my.cnf`

```
server-id=2
binlog-do-db=dbtest
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

reiniciamos los servicios y creamos la base datos dbtest

```
mysql>  create database dbtest
```

ahora importamos nuestra copia de base datos que creamos en el `primary database`

```
mysql -u root -p dbtest <  dbtest.sql
```

nos conectamos a la `standby database` y ejecutamos

```
mysql>  CREATE USER ' repuser' @' localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY ' 123'  
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql>  GRANT ALL ON rep.* TO ' repuser' @' localhost'  
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>  GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO ' repuser' @' %'  IDENTIFIED BY ' 123'  
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>  FLUSH PRIVILEGES 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

ahora bien los parametros:

1. MASTER_HOST='192.168.5.103' **ip del servidor primario**
2. MASTER_USER='repuser' **usuario creado en el servidor primario**
3. MASTER_PASSWORD='123' **el password que le dimos al usuario en la
4. primaria** MASTER_LOG_POS=323  **el parametro position guardado
   anteriormente**
5. MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001' **el parametro file guardado
   anteriormete**

ahora nos conectamos nuevamente:

```
mysql>  CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=' 192.168.5.103' , MASTER_USER='repuser' , MASTER_PASSWORD='123' , MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001' , MASTER_LOG_POS=323 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)

mysql>  SLAVE START
```

y eso seria todo para crear un replica de nuesra base de datos puedes probar haciendo insert en la `primary database`y luego un select en la `standby`

Answer (score -2):

pues bien podrías crear un script de php con 2 dblinks distintos y bien ejecutar las sentencias para crear las DB, mirá no es tan complicado, es algo así:

```
<?php
//Datos servidor 1
$ip1 = '';
$usuario1 = '';
$password1='';
$baseDatos1='';
//Datos servidor 2
$ip2 = '';
$usuario2='';
$password2='';
$baseDatos2='';

//Conectamos el primer servidor
$server1 = new mysqli($ip1, $usuario1, $password1, $baseDatos1);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "No se logro conectar Servidor 1 : ".$mysqli->connect_errno." ".$mysqli->connect_error;
die();
}else{
    //Conectamos el server 2
    $server2 = new mysqli($ip2, $usuario2, $password2, $baseDatos2);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
       echo "No se logro conectar Servidor 2 : ".$mysqli->connect_errno." ".$mysqli->connect_error;
      die();
   }else{
     //Que tabla vamos a copiar del servidor 1
     $tabla='tutabla';
     //Hacemos un select del Schema de la tabla que vamos a copiar en el Servidor 1
     if($rs1 = $servidor1->query("SHOW CREATE TABLE $tabla")){
        if($rs1->num_rows > 0){
           $data1 = $rs1->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
             if($rs2 = $servidor2->query($data1[1])){
                 echo "Perfecto todo funciono como debe ser. ";
             }
        }
     }
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Pero la pregunta no menciona el uso de PHP

Comment: Jajajaja tienes razón... nunca me percaté de ello... tal vez por eso jamás dio seguimiento el compañero.

Comment: No hagan esto por favor, es la pesima recomendacion.... ALERTA !